# How does the compiler in Java decide on unreachable code?

Tags: java, dead-code

How does a compiler decide on with unreachable code?

consider these

```
public class Test15 {

    public static final boolean verdict = false;
    public static final int verdictInt = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // case1
        if (verdict) {
            System.out.println(1);
        } else {
            System.out.println(2);
        }// compiles

        //case 2
        int val = 5;
        switch (val) {
         case verdictInt:System.out.println(3);
                        break;
        }// compiles

        //case 3
        while (false) {

        }// does not compile

        //case 4
        return 6;
        return 7;
        //does not compile

    }
}
```

So when the compiler decides that code is unreachable.Is it because of (for a lack of a better term) hard code(like case 4).Because as per my knowledge, verdict,verdictInt also qualify as compile time constants and according too.
And as per my reading,being able to use the constant verdictInt as a switch case label indicates that it is a compile time constant.

Please let me know in case there are any basic flaws in my reasoning.

Comment: Based on the rules defined in its [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21).

Comment: I combed SO searching for an answer.Should have just gone to the source.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) section on unreachable code is a good, but long read.  I'll condense it into what translates for your question.

### Case 1:

`verdict` could be seen as a flag variable; it may or may not be used for debug purposes.  If it is, then breaking compilation would result in a major design goal miss. The specification explicitly calls this out:

> The rationale for this differing treatment [with `if` as opposed to `while`] is to allow programmers to
>   define "flag variables" such as:
>
> ```
> static final boolean DEBUG = false;
> ```
>
> and then write code such as:
>
> ```
> if (DEBUG) { x=3; }
> ```
>
> The idea is that it should be possible to change the value of DEBUG
>   from false to true or from true to false and then compile the code
>   correctly with no other changes to the program text.

### Case 2:

Your `switch` statement can complete normally by the rules of the JLS:

> A `switch` statement can complete normally iff at least one of the following is true:
>
> - The `switch` block is empty or contains only switch labels.
> - The last statement in the `switch` block can complete normally.
> - There is at least one `switch` label after the last `switch` block statement group.
> - The `switch` block does not contain a `default` label.
> - There is a reachable `break` statement that exits the `switch` statement.

Your `switch` doesn't have a `default` label, so your switch can complete normally.  It just falls out of the switch.

### Case 3:

This explicitly does **not** compile.  Case 1 called some attention to it, but here it's spelled out, emphasis mine:

> A `while` statement can complete normally iff at least one of the
>   following is true:
>
> - The `while` statement is reachable and the condition expression is not    a constant expression (§15.28) with value `true`.
> - There is a reachable `break` statement that exits the `while` statement.
>
> **The contained statement is reachable iff the `while` statement is reachable and the condition expression is not a constant expression
>   whose value is `false`.**

The condition expression is `false`, so you can't reach the contained statement, by definition.

### Case 4:

`return` is a special case; it [completes abruptly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1).  Once a statement completes abruptly, any statements after that are not reachable by definition.

Answer (score 0):

In case 3, it knows it is not a loop because the value is always false.
In case 4, it knows that there have been an infinite loop before, so it says unreachable code.
But return 7; is unreachable also because there is return 6; before it that always run.

It is like doing :

```
printf("Hello");
return 0;
printf("Never reached code");
```

I don't know if this will give an unreachable error :

```
final int i = 5; float x = 0;
while(i<8) {
    x += 0.001f; 
    // Do Nothing
}
printf("Hello World");
```

Comment: Case 3 is an infinite loop?

Comment: @Tom no it's not it's while(false)

Comment: @DanKing I know, but Begah writes that.

Comment: My bad, it isn't, wrote to quick. I will fix it.